# Why is my webserver in golang not handling concurrent requests?

Tags: go

This simple HTTP server contains a call to time.Sleep() that makes
each request take five seconds. When I try quickly loading multiple
tabs in a browser, it is obvious that each request
is queued and handled sequentially. How can I make it handle concurrent requests?

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "net/http"
   "time"
)

func serve(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello, world.")
   time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
}

func main() {
   http.HandleFunc("/", serve)
   http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil) 
}
```

Actually, I just found the answer to this after writing the question, and it is very subtle. I am posting it anyway, because I couldn't find the answer on Google. Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the answer you found?

Comment: The problem was in the way I tested. Web browsers limit the number of connections they make to any one server, even between tabs.

Comment: You may also like to use jMeter to issue request to your server

Comment: You should also see the number of your CPU with `runtime.NumCPU()` and set it with`runtime.GOMAXPROCS(numCPU)`. If numCPU equal to 1, concurency will not occur, because the process will only be executed on one CPU.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Your program already handles the requests concurrently. You can test it with `ab`, a benchmark tool which is shipped with Apache 2:

```
ab -c 500 -n 500 http://localhost:1234/
```

On my system, the benchmark takes a total of 5043ms to serve all 500 concurrent requests. **It's just your browser which limits the number of connections per website.**

Benchmarking Go programs isn't that easy by the way, because you need to make sure that your benchmark tool isn't the bottleneck and that it is also able to handle that many concurrent connections. Therefore, it's a good idea to use a couple of dedicated computers to generate load.

Comment: I want to edit your answer to remove the word "Go" from that last paragraph … ;-)

Comment: Im trying to understand the code: do we imply that http.HandleFunc() spawns a goroutine to handle the request and so it returns immediately?

Comment: The goroutines are spawned much earlier. http.ListenAndServe accepts new connections in an infinite loop and spawns new goroutines to handle them.

Comment: That's good to know. I wish the package documentation and the many examples Ive seen online made this point clearer :-)

Comment: You should also see the number of your CPU with `runtime.NumCPU()` and set it with`runtime.GOMAXPROCS(numCPU)`. If numCPU equal to 1, concurency will not occur, because the process will only be executed on one CPU.

Comment: If you get a 'socket: Too many open files (24)' error, increase the shell resource limit with `ulimit -n <new-limit>`, where `<new-limit>` is e.g. 512.

Answer (score 14):

From Server.go , the go routine is spawned in the Serve function when a connection is accepted. Below is the snippet,  :-

```
// Serve accepts incoming connections on the Listener l, creating a 
// new service goroutine for each.  The service goroutines read requests and
// then call srv.Handler to reply to them.
func (srv *Server) Serve(l net.Listener) error {
        for {
            rw, e := l.Accept()
               if e != nil {
......
            c, err := srv.newConn(rw)
            if err != nil {
                continue
            }
            c.setState(c.rwc, StateNew) // before Serve can return
            go c.serve()
        }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

If you use xhr request, make sure that xhr instance is a local variable.

For example, `xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()` is a global variable. When you do parallel request with the same xhr variable you receive only one result. So, you must declare xhr locally like this `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()`.